# dark activities with android compat without actionbar?

Tags: android, themes, android-appcompat

How can I implement dark screens without actionbar in the appcompat theme? I have implemented the navigation drawer, where the theme comes from style.xml.

Here's my current theme:

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simple.

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

Comment: oh, ok, such simple :-D do you also know how I can change the color of my navigation drawer? It's stil white^^

Comment: set backgrount for drawer's layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your **onCreate** method of Activity, like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
}
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar for AppCompatActivity

Comment: yes for AppCompatActivity you can use getSupportActionBar

Answer (score 0):

This would be your styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.AppCompat</item>

</style>

<style name="Theme.Custom.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Custom.Dark</item>

</style>
```